# I changed .jar to open with windows explorer, and now i can't change it to anything else

Tags: windows-7, jar

I recently changed the Default application for .jar files to be windows explorer, thinking that it would unzip them. I have since gotten a jar decompiler and would like to make windows explorer not the default application to open jar files ( as it basically crashes my computer). Nothing works, i have tried changing the default application by clicking open with, but the check box is greyed out. I have tried going Start menu -> Default Programs -> Associate a file type, but .jar doesn't even appear in the list. I have been googling for a couple hours now and can not find any response that isn't basically those two steps.

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this mess i made ?

Comment: Have you tried to install an application (like WinRAR) which will change default open application to WinRAR? Or you may change it in Registry

Comment: I tried installing winRar, it didn't take the association from windows explorer. Do you have specific advice for changing it in the registry?

Comment: I've navigated to HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.jar and the value for the default key is in fact WinRar, but it still opens with windows explorer

Answer (score 1):

Right click on a .jar, go to "Open With" > "Choose default program..." should do the trick. But you already did that, and "Choose default program..." was grayed out.

**Edit:**

Try FileTypesMan from Nirsoft

http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/file_types_manager.html

Go to .jar and select it, then you can see actions at the bottom and remove or edit them.

Comment: Hmm. Ouch. If it wasn't 1 line without enter/returns I would have. Still my bad.

Try this:
http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/file_types_manager.html

You can go to the .jar and click it, then at the bottom you can see the actions defined for the .jar.

Answer (score 0):

I Was able to fix it by messing around in the registry.

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts.jar\UserChoice

needed to be deleted. that let me choose a new default program for.jar files. Thank you for the responses.

Cheers.